# How to analyse twitter image with azure

Tags: azure

I fetched different data from twitter, one of those is the url with the twitter twitter profile image. So I have an SQLT database with all these information.
Now how can I use azure to analyze each image and understand if the account is a woman or man and the age?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the computer vision, part of the cognitive services. Inside tags, you'll find if it had detected a man or a woman:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

Comment: if you check the link I've shared, you'll find the code from the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-sdk